# Should limited options be stored in a global array vs database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simple question, but not sure how it's best approached. When dealing with a small number of options for a user, is it best to store it in a database or in a global array or some other way?

As an example, I want to have budgets that a user can select from. One option is that I made an initializer file with the available options:

```
BUDGETS = ['Negotiable', '< $500', '$501-1000', '$1000-5000', '> $5000' ]
```

Another option would be to create a Budget table and list those same options. Seems overkill and that I would be querying the database a lot for such a simple set of data. Although, it would probably be more easily edited moving forward?

Ultimately, I ran into a problem when trying to filter the results on the index page using the global array. I had difficulty sending something like '< $500' through the GET string for querying... so started thinking about making a global Hash instead. Started getting complicated, so figure there is a straightforward way to do this.

Comment: database is better because it gives you more flexibility. you can later change it based on the user and it is more secure. using global variables in most cases is not recommended and it is considered a bad practice.

Comment: you can create a method in helper for returning that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For permanence you have to keep the data on disk somewhere.

You can use YAML data files, which make it easy for you to modify without opening some database front-end or writing admin pages. YAML files are also easily read from other programming languages, so you aren't limited to Ruby reading the same resources.

Later, when you're ready to step up to a real system, and move the data into a database or data-store, where it truly belongs, you can easily read those same records and insert them.

In either case, if the resources aren't going to consume huge amounts of memory needed by the application for other things, you can pull them into a Hash and access them from it. Again, YAML fits into that easily, just as an ORM retrieving from a database will.

There are a lot more sophisticated ways of handling the problem using caches and in-memory data-stores of various types, that will outrun a database, but those would be way down the road for your system.

Answer (score 0):

[simple_enum](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum) gem seems good for this purpose.

By the way, enums will implemented in ActiveRecord soon: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html